# Issues Posting Questions?

Tags: bug

Was there a problem with the site a few minutes ago?  I tried to post a question and received a very terse error message in a red box:

`An error occurred submitting the question.`

It happened many times over several minutes, and I was also unable to post this question due to the same error.

Comment: I've had that too on different occasions. Did you paste a large amount of data from a notepad into the input field and then try to save it? Are you behind a corporate firewall?

Comment: No, and no.  I saved the data into notepad and posted it just fine a few minutes later.  The question I tried to post here was even smaller.  They failed repeatedly, then worked a few minutes later from the exact same system and browser.